# Using the ref attribute with dom element outside a VueJS 2 component template

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am currently struggling with referencing existing DOM elements with VueJS.

I have an existing date input rendered from the applications twig template and a separate VueJS widget i integrated.

`<input type="time" ref="date_time_1" min="09:00" max="18:00" value="13:30">`

The date input field is NOT inside the components template, but within the VueJS application (having `id="#app"`).

For data-binding i would like to use the `ref` attribute to connect the VueJS component with my date input field inside the components template (e.g. for initialization with values coming from the application):

```
mounted() {
  componentsTimeValue: this.$refs["date_time_1"].value;
}
```

getting `undefined` here.

Is there a way to connect "existing" DOM elements (that are not created with vue), with vue components using the `ref` attribute at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though not a good practise because #div container is handed over to vue for manipulation but still you can reference the dom that weren't created by vue but lie inside #app

For that you must reference properly, so if you are in some child component you use

```
mounted() {
  componentsTimeValue: this.$root.$refs["date_time_1"].value;
}
```